# XPROC p:file-mkdir not found

Tags: xproc

I'm using XPROC and the XPROC Processor MorganaXProc-IIIse. I'm actually just trying to create a directory through XPROC. However, all I get is this error message:

```
No visible declaration for '{http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step/filesystem}file-mkdir' found: Check spelling, imports or @use-when values.
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" xmlns:pf="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step/filesystem" name="pipeline" version="3.0">
    <p:variable name="base.dir" select="'.'"/>
    <pf:file-mkdir href="${basedir}/lib"/>
</p:declare-step>
```

Since documentation is very limited, any hint is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does `<p:file-mkdir href="${basedir}/lib"/>` instead of `<pf:file-mkdir href="${basedir}/lib"/>` work?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hah, yes that works, thanks. If you post your solution as an answer, I'll mark it as the right solutions. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of XProc 3, the `file-mkdir` step is in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc` so using the prefix `p` your pipeline declares for that should work: `<p:file-mkdir href="${basedir}/lib"/>` instead of `<pf:file-mkdir href="${basedir}/lib"/>`.